# What is the right way to preload ad on compose?

Tags: android, admob, android-jetpack-compose

**What I want:** I want to be able to load ads on one screen and show it on another screen. I found some code to do this but only with an interstitial ad, I tried to do this with a rewarded ad and it works but I don't know if it's fine/safe or if there is a better or easier way to do this.

**My Code:**

```
**AdMob kt file:**
var mRewardedAd: RewardedAd? = null
private val _isAdRewardGranted = MutableLiveData(RewardModel())
val isAdRewardGranted: MutableLiveData<RewardModel> get() = _isAdRewardGranted

fun showRewardedAd(context: Context, reward: String) {
    val activity = context.findActivity()
    if (mRewardedAd != null) {
        mRewardedAd?.show(activity!!){
            Timber.i("AdMob | User earned the reward.")
            changeIsAdRewardGranted(true, reward)
        }
    } else {
        Timber.i("AdMob | The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.")
    }
}

fun getIsAdRewardGranted(): MutableLiveData<RewardModel> {
    return isAdRewardGranted
}

fun changeIsAdRewardGranted(isRewardGranted: Boolean, reward: String){
    _isAdRewardGranted.value = RewardModel(isRewardGranted, reward)
}

data class RewardModel(
    var isAdRewardGranted: Boolean = false,
    val reward: String = ""
)

**ViewModel:**
private var _uiState by mutableStateOf(ShopState())
val uiState: ShopState get() = _uiState
val getIsAdRewardGranted = getIsAdRewardGranted()

fun onEvent(event: ShopEvents){
    when (event){
        is OnChangeIsRewardedAdShow -> {
            _uiState = _uiState.copy(isRewardedAdShow = event.show)
        }
        is OnRewardGranted -> {
            changeIsAdRewardGranted(false, event.reward)
            Timber.i("Reward ${event.reward} granted")
        }
    }
}

**Screen:**
val isRewardGranted by shopViewModel.getIsAdRewardGranted.observeAsState()
LaunchedEffect(key1 = isRewardGranted){
    if (isRewardGranted?.isAdRewardGranted == true){
        shopViewModel.onEvent(ShopEvents.OnRewardGranted(isRewardGranted!!.reward))
    }
}
LaunchedEffect(key1 = uiState.isRewardedAdShow){
    if (uiState.isRewardedAdShow){
        showRewardedAd(context, "clue")
        loadRewardedAd(context)
        shopViewModel.onEvent(OnChangeIsRewardedAdShow(false))
    }
}
// on button click shopViewModel.onEvent(OnChangeIsRewardedAdShow(true))
// ad loaded from activity when app start
```